# Distance Metric for a dataset with embeddings and numerical columns

Tags: similarity, embeddings, distance, semantic-similarity

I'm trying to build an Approximate Nearest Neighbours model that can fetch similar records in a dataset, that are contextually similar. For example, for a record of job=**Software Engineer** and age=**25**, a similar record could be job=**Programmer** and age=**24**.

To achieve this, I'm converting the string columns into their embeddings and scaling the numerical columns. Generally, people use cosine distance to measure similarity between embeddings and euclidean distance to measure similarity between numerical values. I'm using [miniLM](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2) to get sentence embeddings for text columns.

Is it fine if I append the embeddings to their respective numerical values as a single vector? If so, then what is a proper approach to measure the distance between such vectors? Is there any domain where research has been conducted on this problem?